# Is the set of affine varieties countable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Intuitively, if a complex affine variety $X$ is given by polynomials
$$f_i(z_1,\ldots,z_n)=\sum_{j=0}^na_{ij}z_i^j,\quad i=1,\ldots,k,$$
for some $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}$ then we can perturbe the coefficients $a_{ij}$ *very* slightly so that they lie in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and the new variety is still isomorphic to $X$. Thus, we would conclude that the set of affine varieties, up to isomorphisms, is at most countable. Is that intuition correct? And can we make that argument rigorous?

**Edit.** We might encounter problems with singularities, but can we use that argument to at least show that there are countably many *smooth* affine varieties?

**Background material:** A complex affine variety is a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (for some $n\geq1$) given by the zero set of a collection of finitely many polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_k\in\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]$. Two affine varieties are isomorphic if their coordinate ring $A(X):=\mathbb{C}[z_1,\ldots,z_n]/\langle f_1,\ldots,f_k\rangle$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro If the intuition in the first sentence is true, then yes we can conclude countability (rigorously). But the question is precisely if that first sentence is true.

Comment: If you restrict to cubic curves in $\mathbb{C}^2$, all elliptic curves occur here and they are parametrized by their $j$-function. So, there are already uncountably many non-isomorphic cubic curves.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks. Are there uncountably many smooth cubic curves?

Comment: @SHP yes, each elliptic curve that Mohan discusses is smooth. So there are uncountably many non-isomorphic smooth cubic curves.